# The MS VSCode is not showing any errors

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I included tine.h which is my typo, but it does not show any errors. Then, I entered in "dsfjdskljcf" to make sure this is wrong. But it did not show any errors. I think I clicked don't show the errors thing, but still, I don't know how to *fix* it. I edited the settings, searched the net, but I couldn't find ANY solutions. What is the exact problem going around in this VS code? How can I fix it?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMMxS.png)

Comment: What are your C compiler/build and Intellisense settings? Considerably more info is needed.

Comment: I am using VScode C extension and It used to show errors. Simply I don't know why the error is not showing.

Comment: @JihwanAhn Go to settings, Check, if Error Squiggles are enabled or not

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this VSCode error appens to me, but it go away after restart the program.
Maybe that's obvious i know. If you didn't try yet, try